# Solving sudoku - backtracking algorithm does not backtrack - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I have spent many hours thinking about a way to implement the Sudoku solving algorithm based on backtracking. However, I have encountered a problem - the algorithm does not backtrack once it does an error. To make things as simple as possible, this is my main function:

```
public class Sudoku {
    private int[][] grid = new int[9][9];
    private int col;
    private int row;

    public boolean solveSudoku() {
        if(!(this.FindEmptyCell())) {
            return true;
        }

        for(int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
            if(this.isPossible(this.col, this.row, num)) {
                this.grid[this.col][this.row] = num;
                if(this.solveSudoku()) {
                    return true;
                }
                this.grid[col][row] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The constructor of the Sudoku class creates an empty board and then the computer has to fill in the entire grid with numbers satisfying the rules of Sudoku. 
 The FindEmptyCell method sets the values of the fields row and column equal to the indices of the first unoccupied cell. 
And this grid represents the state when my program returned false:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 5 6 1 2 3 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Could you, please, tell me if everything - up to this point - is correct with my algorithm? If so, that would mean that the error lies somewhere in the auxiliary functions. For example, I do not know whether or not the use of fields to store the indices does not prevent backtracking. 
Any help would be appreciated. Also, if this post has to some extent violated the rules of this board, please inform me in the comments prior to downvoting - I want to avoid these mistakes in the future.

EDIT: Provided remaining methods:

```
public Sudoku() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public boolean FindEmptyCell(int col, int row) {
    for(col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
        for(row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            if(this.grid[col][row] == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean usedInRow(int row, int num) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
        if(grid[col][this.row] == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean usedInColumn(int col, int num) {
    for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        if(grid[this.col][row] == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean usedInBox(int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            if(grid[col+boxStartCol][row + boxStartRow] == num) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isPossible(int col, int row, int number) {
    return !(this.usedInRow(this.row, number)) && !this.usedInColumn(this.col, number) && !this.usedInBox(row - row%3, col-col%3, number);
}
```

Comment: With recursive algorithms you want to call something like `solveSudoku(Sudoku sudoku);` Your approach looks like non-recursive attempt.

Comment: Having only one copy of the `grid` is ok. But only having one copy of `row` and `col` is definitely not ok.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question unfortunately. I think we'd probably require the other functions as well (i.e., `FindEmptyCell`, `isPossible`). Also, based on what I'm reading, I don't know how you're incrementing the `row`/`col` values. Do you mind pasting those additional functions?

Comment: @Mike  Thanks, I have provided the remaining methods.

Comment: So, maybe it's unrelated, but you don't look like you're referencing your parameters `row` and `col` in `usedInRow` and `usedInColumn`. You're referencing `this.row` and `this.col` instead. Start there and see if that helps.

Comment: `FindEmptyCell` takes a `row` and a `col` as parameters, but `solveSudoku` calls it with no parameters. Note that *"questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"*. It's not possible to help you unless you post real code that actually compiles and runs.

Comment: I have solved my problem - it was enough to create new local variables <code>int row = this.row<code> and <code>int col = this.col<code>. I cannot believe that it was so simple.

Comment: Congrats on solving it, good for you. Allow me to suggest that you delete the question, please. IMHO it will not be useful for future readers.